# Xamarin ClassNotFoundException when building

Tags: java, xaml, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms

I receive this error when trying to build a Xamarin.Forms project on Visual Studio 2017:
`java/lang/ClassNotFoundException: error in opening JAR file <Zip file open error> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\rt.jar`

I tried closing and opening VS, and deleting the lib+obj directories and rebuilding. Nothing works so far..

The only change was that I added "Binding" into the a xaml page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the other developer was using another JDK version.